# Regex: Split by *

Tags: regex

I would like to split a string by `*` and just take the first value.

My string looks like that:

```
tes*product*p2131öä*test
```

I tried simply doing something like `\*[1]`, however this does not work.

Any recommendation how to split a string by `*` and only take the first part?

I appreciate your replies

Comment: Use: `([^*]+)` to capture everything up to the first `*`

Comment: Why `[1]`? Maybe you want `{1}` but it is useless.

Comment: If you're purely splitting the string, take a look at whatever string routines your language provides, there's probably one dedicated to splitting strings

Comment: @MohitBhasi Optimal result would be if I could take the string I want from the regex. Like also the second or the third: `tes`,`product`,`p2131öä` or `test`.

Comment: Has whatever language you're using got a `split()` function? If so then regex might be unnecessary.

Comment: @mrquad which language? as regex wont suffice in your case

Comment: I am parsing the things in dvs, which is a scientific parsing framework from our faculty and does not support any split method, only regex(I know its lol!!)

Comment: just `^[^*]+` would be fine.

Comment: what app language are you using?

Comment: If you are using java try doing `\\*`